# .remove() is removing two instances of tuple in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a coding challenge where I have to remove duplicates of tuples in a list.

Right now, the .remove() method seems to be removing both my (1,1) tuples and not the (2,2) tuple.

```
def remove_duplicates(lis):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        print(f"We are at i = {i}")
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lis)):
            
            print(f"j={j}")
            print(f"This is lis[i] {lis[i]}")
            print(f"This is lis[j] {lis[j]}")

            if lis[i] == lis[j]:
                to_remove = lis[j]
                lis.reverse() # reversal is done to remove the last matching element
                lis.remove(lis[j]) 
                lis.reverse() 
    print(lis)
    return lis

lis = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,2), (1,1)] 
remove_duplicates(lis) # should return [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Life is much simpler if you build a new list, then replace the elements of `lis` with the contents of the new list if necessary. The overhead should be comparable to (or less than!) the repeated resizing of the original list when you remove an item.

Comment: You are also going to have problems because you are removing items from a list while iterating over it. Once you have removed an element, the list is shorter and the index `i` or `j` may become out of bounds. See the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates, you can transform your list to a `set` and back to `list`:

```
def remove_duplicates(lis):
    return list(set(lis))
```

Comment: But note that this won't keep the order of the original list.

Comment: This assumes the elements of `lis` are hashable and that the order of the elements in the new list doesn't matter.

Comment: The op appears to be asking why remove isn't removing an element, not for a rewrite of their code